# MVC foreach loop styling

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm new to the MVC foreach loop styling. How do I style the @item.QuizForHint?  I did tried putting #QuizForHint but it's did not work. The @item.QuizForHint will be getting the data from the database.

```
@foreach (var item in Model){

        <a href="@("#QuizForHint"+i)" id="getAnsHint"  class="btn"  data-toggle="collapse">Quiz Hint</a>
        <div id="@("QuizForHint"+i)" class="collapse">
            @item.QuizForHint

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The styling you give for class `collapse` will be applicable of `@item.QuizForHint`.
If you want specific styling apart from the `div`, then you can place `@item.QuizForHint` within a span and style the span.

```
@foreach (var item in Model){

    <a href="@("#QuizForHint"+i)" id="getAnsHint"  class="btn"  data-toggle="collapse">Quiz Hint</a>
    <div id="@("QuizForHint"+i)" class="collapse">
            <span class="stylish">@item.QuizForHint</span>
    </div>

}
```

Comment: @Rod, I have updated the answer. You can add extra style by adding style to class "stylish".

Comment: I managed to get the item to be styled. Since it's a Bootstrap collapse, i can't hide it after I clicked the Quiz Hint button. Any ideas what's wrong with it? @Habeeb